# Permission denied on cat via shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, permission-denied

I have an issue with running cat in shell script on a log file which is in ~/bin/rclone_sync_ACD.log. This is the line in the shell script:

```
RESULT=cat $LOGFILE | tail -1
```

But when running the script I get:

```
./rclone_sync: line 63: /Users/pjburnhill/bin/rclone_sync_ACD.log: Permission denied
```

In terminal, if I type `cat $LOGFILE | tail -1`, it gives the right output.

What permissions would the script need to have to access and print out the correct line?

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: `RESULT=cat $LOGFILE | tail -1` runs `$LOGFILE` as a command (and it's probably not executable, hence the error). You probably want `RESULT=$(cat $LOGFILE | tail -1)`, or [simply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) `RESULT=$(tail -1 "$LOGFILE")`. This is really basic stuff: You might want to read a shell scripting tutorial.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net). It automatically detects [your problem](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2037).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To assign the output of a command to a variable, wrap the command in backticks or `$()`.

```
RESULT=$(cat $LOGFILE | tail -1)
```

Your command performed the environment variable assignment `RESULT=cat`, and then executed the command `$LOGFILE | tail -1` in that environment. Since `$LOGFILE` is not an executable file, you got an error.